Open Sharepoint file for input through VBA
I’m using a text file on a shard network drive to store a printer specification but we want to move the file to Sharepoint due to cross team access issues. Large company, easier to manage access to a sharepoint file than network drive entitlements.
The macro reads the pprinter info before proceeding with other checks.
My current command is:
Open “N:\TPrint.txt” For Input as #1
Simply changing the path to SharePoint doesn’t work. I’ve attempted a couple other solutions I found online to no avail. We are using SharePoint Online.
Any help is appreciated.
I’ve tried the http path, I’ve left iff the http and changed / to.

Many of the options in VBA for working with text files will not work with a HTTP path - they are for local files or files on network shares.  What is the use case for the file?  Do many people need to write to it, how frequently, etc. etc.

My belief is that vba does not play well with files on SharePoint or OneDrive. It can work with the synced version of those files locally stored.

Sure would be nice if MS could offer up some kind of library or FSO equivalent which played nice with SP, now that so many of us have moved so much content there.

Oepn For Input only works for local files. You could do the solution from the other Comments. I had the same issue and i handled it with saving a ms word/excel file in the sharepoint and opening it via workbooks.open(Filepath) to read it. It is more code, but it works. I can send you an examplecode later

In this case we have hundreds of users, and over 300 templates, where they want to force the users to print these documents to a specific network printer. Historically they embedded the printer name in the macro. And of course now there is a need to change the printer name. I’m trying to steer them towards a solution that will not embed the name is each template.

In that case my answer should work OK.

If you only need to read a file:
Sub TestRead()
    Debug.Print TextContent("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/TestLibrary/test3.txt")
End Sub

Function TextContent(url) As String
    With CreateObject("microsoft.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        If .Status = 200 Then
            TextContent = .responseText
        End If
    End With
End Function


This Function takes in the FilePath of an Excelfile located in a Sharepoint.
It will open the file, read all cells from A1 to the last cell down, which is not empty.
It will close your "Server" again and return the Text.
Public Function ReadPrinter(FilePath As String) As String

    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Text As String
    
    WB.Open FilePath
    Set Rng = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Do Until rng.Offset(i, 0).Formula = ""
        Text = Text & rng.Offset(i, 0).Formula
    Loop
    WB.Close(True) 'SaveChanges = True
    ReadPrinter = Text

End Function

I use this (with errorhandling) in a reallife Application for similar uses like you.
The 2 Values:
Sheet1
A1

Are just an Example.
You still need to implement how to get the text into the Workbook, but that should not be too hard.
